# Fastest insert C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Is there any way to insert data in any position in an array/vector pretty fast, given the array/vector is very large?

If I use vector::insert the vector will move all the items after my item and this will take much time, if for example the vector got 1b items and this is performed at the middle of the vector, the vector will move 500m items.

Is there any efficient way to do this with C style/C++ array or Vector?

Comment: If this is a performance concern, you might start looking into a different container.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size, so you cannot really insert elements into them.

Comment: 500 million items in a vector is kinda pushing it anyway.  You'd need quite a bit of RAM to make that viable, unless they're all of some fundamental type.

Comment: @cHao I don't see the problem. At all. I've worked with much larger data sets in memory. (Also: nice pun :))

Comment: @sehe He said what the problem can be - RAM. You'd need approximately 500MB RAM for every 1 byte of element size. In actual fact the OP said 1b items, so that means 1GB RAM for every 1 byte of element size. That is definitely non-trivial.

Comment: Ah I missed the `1b` reference.

Comment: Sure it's a lot of RAM, but speed is a bigger issue than RAM.

Comment: @JBentley not RAM but virtual memory.  You can have a 1Gb vector without having 1Gb of RAM on your computer.

Comment: I agree a different data structure might be optimal. Perhaps a [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_\(data_structure\))?

Comment: @Johan: Sure, but hitting the disk is slooooooooow. If this is an optimization problem, that's certainly part of the problem.

Comment: @johan Yes, obviously. But that just supports the point - that you can run into issues (such as swapping).

Comment: @Cornstalks obviously. :-)

Comment: Guys, given the user will have at least 4GB RAM, and my program will need 1GB, is there any way to be 100% sure virtual memory will NOT be used?

Comment: @luka Disable memory paging in the OS? But really you shouldn't concern yourself with this and instead trust that the OS knows what it is doing. A sensible OS won't just swap your vector to the HD randomly if there is RAM available. And if it does swap, it is because it needs the RAM for some other purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Theory (Specifically Big O notation) says that linked lists have O(1) complexity for insertion and removal, and dynamic arrays have O(n), due to the container shifting that the erase/insert needs.

**But thats theory. Computers are not only theory. In practice its far different**.

Modern computers have their memory arranged in a so called *memory-hierarchy*, that is, a set o different types of memory devices sorted by its speed:

```
+---------------+
| CPU registers |   ^
+---------------+   |
|   L1 cache    |   |
|      ...      |   |   Less apacity
|   LN cache    |   |   Faster access
+---------------+   |   More expensive hardware
|      RAM      |   |
+---------------+   
|      HDD      |
+---------------+
```

As the diagram shows, the hierarchy is organized through the speed of the memory access. But note that more speed means more expensive hardware, so this translates to **many slow-access memory and a few fast memory**.
So one way to boost your program performance is **to hold frecuently used data in fast memory**, and only go to the slow memory when is necessary (The program requests data which is not loaded in the fast memory, for example).

Thats exactly what the hardware does, supposing two behaviors:

- If a piece of data is requested, probably data near to it will be requested in the future. This is called [*Locality of reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). Consider how we use arrays, for example.
- If a piece of data is requested, probably it will be requested again in the future. Thats called *temporal locality*. Again, iterating over and array again and again is an example of that.

Of course memory is limited, so a request of new data which will be loaded in a certain level of the hierarchy discards the data which was there before.

So, **why is this important for the performance of different containers?**

Remember how a linked-list (`std::list` is a linked-list) woks:
A linked list is a chain of separated nodes conected between them through pointers:

```
+---+     +---+             +---+
| 1 | --> | 2 | --> ... --> | N |
+---+     +---+             +---+
```

On the other hand, a dynamic array (`std::vector` is a dynamic array) is **a continuous chunk of memory**:

```
+---+---+-----+---+
| 1 | 2 | ... | N |
+---+---+-----+---+
```

As I said above, the theory sais that linked-list insertion/removal has O(1) complexity, because *"is just changing pointers"*. But consider how do you access the memory to do that. **Have you notices that process does not fulfill the space-locality rule?**. So this has a lot of misses (cache misses), that is, new memory out of the fast memory is requested, and performance goes down.
In fact, even if theory says that transversing a linked-list has O(n) complexity, in practice together with the complexity are the continous performance hits due to the cache misses.

Now consider how a dynamic array works: Its true that inserting/removing has O(n) complexity, because you have to shift one position one side of the array to leave a gap for the new element, or eliminate that gap if you are erasing.
**But** remember that an array is a contiguous block of memory, so if you are using it, probably that array is totally (Or almost partially) loaded into the fast memory (*sapce-locality*), so **the shiftting process is really fast**.

So as you can see, **the dynamic array is far faster than the linked list in modern architectures**.

In general, `std::vector` has many advantages opposed to `std::list`:

- Its cache-frindly. As we have discussed, `std::list` is not, and "cache-friendliness" its very important for performance nowadays. This leads to fast insertion/removal, fast random access, and fast copying.
- Linked-lists do one dynamic-memory operation per insertion/deletion. Calls to `malloc()`/`free()` (That is, calls to the OS to retrieve/leave heap memory) take a lot of time. On the other hand, dynamic arrays only do de/allocations in a O(logn) average.

But thats not all: In a few cases, `std::list` must be preferred, cases where **the cost of copying/moving elements is very high**. The point of the `std::vector` performance is based on the cheap shifting process done at the cache, but if the elements of the vector have certain expensive copy/move semantics, there is no benefit at all and **the list perform better than the vector**.

Read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340797/Number-crunching-Why-you-should-never-ever-EVER-us) for more information about the topic.

Comment: "linked lists have O(1) complexity for insertion and removal" is only true if you already know where you want to insert/remove. If you first have to `find` that location, you're back to O(n).

Comment: @Sjoerd thats the point. I have written that to clarify, even with without the find process, the vector chache policy performs far better than list. Of course if you have to find the insertion point, its much worse.

Comment: You can always override the allocator to carve pieces from a large chunk and ensure locality of list nodes.

Comment: @Raja of course. You could improve the behavior of the container customizing it (Through the allocator in this case). But I'm talking about the cotainer **as is**. Also if you need to modify the container, its a sign of that you need other container.

Answer (score 2):

C++ vectors are really arrays with smart resizing, if you need to insert at the front of a container you need to consider something else like a linked list. However, have in mind that if performance is very critical to you then such other containers are usually not contiguous in memory so will often incur memory paging issues as you traverse them and jump around in memory. It's always a trade off.

Comment: I don't suggest a linked list here. It will add considerable overhead and might make the system crawl (`std::list` is even allowed to have a O(n) implementation for `size()` until c++11...)

Comment: Can you please explain this memory paging thing? Can I disable it somehow?

Comment: I'd probably look into `std::deque` before `std::list` for insertions to the front.

Comment: @Luka: memory mapping and mlock() on UNIX, VirtualLock on windows. Keep in mind that the degraded locality of reference is going to cost performance for any kind of linear sequential access anyways. (PS. use e.g. Boost IPC allocators with container classes to locate your data in the memory mapped area)

Comment: @Luka, no you can't, it's how the data structure is implemented - each element is allocated on the heap and can end up anywhere in memory so when you iterate you may end up jumping around; arrays on the other hand are guaranteed to be contiguous so iterating is very fast. what else does your application do with the data?

Comment: @sehe, note that he's also inserting in the middle

Comment: Not 100% what I will do with the array as I am designing the function now, but I believe I will just insert lot's of data in random positions and just read them latter. The data will also change.

Comment: If performance is a concern, I always prefer `std::vector` instead of `std::list` due to its cache locality. The performance of list is better than vector only in a few cases, cases where the cost of copying/moving elements is expensive. Else, a vector performs far better.

Comment: @Luka, if you do infrequent updates and a lot of scans then vector would be better, if you do a lot of inserts and infrequent scans then list would probably be better, if you have both then you might have to think of a custom data structure for your need. Additionally, if you only load your data on startup with lots of random inserts you could create that as a list and then when loading is done copy it once to a vector and then just use the vector for further processing...

Comment: I see, is this possible with an easy way?

Comment: @Luka: copying a list to a vector is easy, yes. For example if you have a `list<int> mylist` you create a vector from it with  `vector<int> myvector(mylist.begin(), mylist.end());`